# How to build mysqli lib?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, makefile, configure

How can I create the mysqli lib that I will use when configure php?

I know I should use the flag: --with-mysqli=/path/to/mysql_config. However my question is how do I build the mysqli lib? Is it part of the mysql source? I want to build the lib myself.

```
 wget https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.3.13.tar.gz
 tar xfz php-7.3.13.tar.gz --strip-components 1 -C .
 ./configure --with-mysqli=<where can I find this>
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php
--with-mysqli=/path/to/mysql_config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not so obvious, since you need to specify the path when it's part of the package.

The source code is located under:
./ext/mysqli in the php tar file